# How to auth backend service throught mobile app with Oauth2?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, jwt, single-sign-on

Help me please to understand correct flow to SSO with a mobile app for  backend services

Now I'm using the next scheme:
[image]

1. `My unauthorized mobile app` wants to auth in my service through SSO (facebook and google). It has clientId, clientSecret and required scopes for `My service`.
2. `My mobile app` auth with vendor SDK, for example, on Facebook.
3. `My mobile app` give back authorization token.
4. `My mobile app` sends authorization token in the auth request to `My service`.
5. `My service` uses this token to get information about a user from a remote identity provider. For example, get a user identifier or email with `Facebook Graph API`. This identity used to authenticate and authorize a user (my own RDB).
6. `My service` return JWT token to `My mobile app` (if auth success). This token is used for the next request to `My service` API.

Is it correct to send Oauth2 token from the app to backend?

Can you point out the ​errors of the current approach?